# Electricity usage up with new unit

Tags: hvac

I have a separate post regarding duct sizes but our new unit is using more electricity than older unit.  Both are 3.5 ton.  Prior unit was a 20 year old 10 seer, new one is 14 seer.  The two differences are airflow and cycles.  The prior unit would run and run, sometimes for 90 minutes or more at a time.  Long  run times even in early evenings.  The new unit runs between 11 and 14 minutes on 84 degree days.  On 92 degree days for maybe 23 minutes

So the new unit cycles a whole lot more.  Is that causing my higher electricity usage?

The airflow is much stronger even with a one inch merv 10 filer.  The humidity is usually between 45 and 55%.  The 55% is normally only in the morning hours until the unit comes on. It is a single stage unit. House is 1700 sq ft excluding sunroom.  House gets full sun all day.  Airflow is much stronger even if fan is on low.  They did turn the new air handler to eliminate an angle in the plenum.  The plenum now goes straight up

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit cycling on and off more would have a negligible effect on your usage. Now the air handler is a different store. If the installer upped the size of it than that's where your increase it. That would explain the higher air flow. Most air handlers have different speeds the blower will operate at. Maybe your old unit have a lower speed set and the new unit has a higher setting set. Those motors are usually 1/3 to 1/5 HP and they run all the time the compressor is running unless you have it set to run continually... make sure it's set to "auto". The plenum being rerouted would also help the airflow by eliminating the bend. If the installers replaced the thermostat the calibrations will probably be different and that would also affect the run time of the unit.

Comment: Thanks, Jack.  It stayed a 3.5 so we didn’t increase the tonnage. But the new units push more air plus we improved the plenum. 

I had read that more cycles use more power because it takes more energy to start the unit than run it.  Is that corr?

Comment: The tonnage refers to the compressor unit, usually the outside piece and the air handler is inside. The air handler can be up sized without increasing the tonnage.  The current  to start the unit is greater but it's only for a few seconds and there's a voltage dip so there's no significant increase in usage.

Comment: The air handler blower is set to medium  but does have a low.  Does the low use less electricity and can having it on low cause issues?  I have read it could cause the unit to freeze up since enough air won’t be blowing over it?

Comment: The low uses less electricity but yes, it can cause freeze ups and you would probably have to use a lower merv filter. As  whole, do you notice it cooling better?

Comment: Do you think I am safe running it on low if I use a nom pleated type filter? As you know from other post I am testing with an 8” in plenum.  Still good airflow but the Honeywell pro 8000 is very sensitive.  Still cycles a lot more than old system

Comment: At this point all I can say is to experiment.  Do you have a high setting? Do you have a strip heater in the air handler

Comment: Agreed. The purpose of the air handler is to move the heat-transfer fluid (air in this case) through the chilling unit and distributed to the house. That is the one job. Moving the heat transfer fluid faster than is required for the job is wasteful and useless.

Comment: I have a high, medium and low. I have strong airflow so would prefer to not use high

Comment: I have a question.  I am testing the ability to run an 8” line by leaving a hole in the plenum to simulate airflow loss.  I know that is not the right way but will have to do.  By having the hole in the plenum am I allowing hot air in or causing other impacts while trying to gauge this?  The unit is running longer so the short cycles are better but the humidity is higher than usual inside, even with unit running longer

Comment: You will have reduced flow when you add the duct to the hole. Right now, you're just AC'ing your attic. You're not letting hot air in but letting maximum cold air out.

Comment: Yeah.  Airflow is still decent but unit running much, much longer and humidity high.  Just wondering if opening the hole is having an adverse effect other than losing air.

Comment: Interesting.  Humidity increases when I run the unit with the hole in plenum.  Humidity goes down when I turn it off and it increases when on.  So the hole is having an adverse effect and other than airflow I won’t be able to tell the impact overall.

Comment: you have the hole in the plenum that is really reducing the pressure in the plenum. As a result, the air flow across the coils will be faster and will be less cool causing higher humidity. Once you add the duct to the hole and extend it, the pressure will increase and the airflow across the coils will br reduced and will result in cooler air and lower humidity.

Comment: Sounds like what is happening.  The air doesn’t feel as cold as usual. Humidity this afternoon didn’t come down much considering unit was running for a while.  Considering how long the unit ran today and it cycles I think it is using less energy than when it was running the shorter cycles.  It ran longer today in total hours but used less energy It ran longer today in total hours but used less energy

Comment: Would the same thing happen if there was a hole in one of the trunks and not the plenum?

Comment: Yes, but probably wouldn't have as much effect and would depend on the size of the hole. How are you determining energy use?

Comment: Basically looking at meter. I know not the best way because of other factors.

Comment: So I hooked up the hole in plenum to a 15 foot flex duct that was leftover in the attic and still getting inconsistent humidity inside.  The other end of the flex is not connected to anything.  Does that sound right that I would still have issues since it is just blowing in attic, even on a 15 foot flex?

Comment: It's still venting into an open, vented space unstead of into a sealed room with negative pressure because of the return  to the air handler.

Comment: Ok. I capped the hole so I assume it should be back to normal now

Comment: @jack  System seems back to normal now that I capped the holes.  Thank you so much for helping undeserved the effects of what I was doing.  I think my airflow will be able to support the run. I just need to decide on either an 8” from plenum or two 6” that will wye into an 8. One six from the plenum and one from a trunk leading to a room getting plenty of air.  Either way I will include dampers in case air needs to be adjusted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106663/discussion-between-dominick-orlando-and-jack).

Comment: It’s funny that you mention ductless units.  When we converted the 400 square-foot porch into a sunroom and made it part of the house we put a 2 ton mini split out there.   The problem is when we converted part of that room to a bedroom the mini split is now in that bedroom.   So imagine a 2 ton unit in a 150 square-foot room. The Ductless has worked great for the big room but freezes you out in five minutes in the small room

Comment: We might move the ductless or buy a smaller one for the other part of the sunroom and I really don’t want three air conditioners which is why I would like to get air into the bedroom

Comment: Jack, again I know this isn’t ideal but I really only want to have to do this once so will this test work.  I have an attic entrance in my closet which is near the new bedroom that we want to run the line to.  If I ran the line to that attic entrance and into the closet would that eliminate the pressure issues so I can test out what the airflow will be like in the rest of the house?  There are no stairs in that entrance so I can cut a board out with a hole in the middle so that it is somewhat sealed

Comment: That will give you an indication of what to expect.

Comment: Jack, the way my trunks work is that it makes one gradual turn from the plenum and then it feeds the living room and a couple of bedrooms, however, before that feed it makes a left to feed the rest of the house.  That left causes some lost airflow and while the left of the house has good airflow it isn't as strong as the other part of the house.  Due to that I am  a little concerned with putting an 8" in the plenum to feed the new bedroom.  I am thinking about a 7" in the plenum and a 6" from the other part of the house and then wye it and have a 7 or 8" to the bedroom.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: At this point all we're doing is guessing, a 7" duct verses an 8" duct.  I think, in the end,  splitting your ductless system into two zones: sun room and bedroom, would give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: I don’t disagree but I think I need to redirect some of the airflow.  The air comes on and you feel cold in some rooms after a few minutes

Comment: @jack.  Jack, I ran my test into the closet. I have 25 feet of 8” flex stretched tight from plenum.  This is reduced to 6” flex about 20 feet.  The airflow is pretty good and the other vents in the house are still good.  Do you think reducing to a 6” is the right thing or is reducing to a 7 better?  I had read for long runs to reduce two inches.  Just wondering if I would get more airflow reducing to a 7

Comment: I think the six will be fine.....  If the other vents are OK, go with the 6... stay safe out there.

Comment: Yeah.  The other vents seem good.  I did downgrade on the filter a little to allow for more airflow

Comment: @jack.  I haven’t tested yet but from the feel of it the test air doesn’t seem as cold as other vents. It is around 75 outside and cloudy.  Flex has R6.  Does flex not keep air as cold?  Attic isn’t very hot right now

Comment: It's the distance that doing that. The air in those ducts will be warm when AC kicks in .

Comment: Is there any way to help with that?

Comment: @jack.  Or are you saying it will only be warm for a minute after ac kicks on?  Even after a few minutes it doesn’t feel quite as cold as other ducts.  It isn’t warm, just not as cold. I think it has R 6.  Anything I can do?  Wrap it with more insulation?

Comment: @DominickOrlando  It will cool off a bit after a minute or two but it won't be as cool as the shorter runs of ducts.  I think you're on the verge of pushing this beyond the design limits of the system. The longer the air is in the ducts the less cool it will be.

Comment: @jack. That does make sense. The shorter run I am comparing it to is off a main trunk that is around 47 feet in total.  Maybe that air stays cooler in fiberboard

Comment: @jack.  I picked up a hvac thermometer. I am getting a differential of 17 between supply and return.  In the bedroom the differential is 19.  While I think 17 is within range, maybe bottom of range, I can tell the 2 degree difference to bedroom.  Do you think the differential will decrease as attic gets hotter?

Comment: I'm not sure what the differential is that you're talking about.

Comment: @jack.  Jack, I can use a little help. With the test I am doing with the vent going in the closet I noticed that the humidity level would increase when the air came on, and sometimes it will go back down as the air runs a little bit.  I put everything back the way it was and the humidity level is still increasing when the air comes on.   I checked the condensation drain and it is pouring out water and the thermostat does reach the temperature within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I don’t recall the humidity increasing last night and especially before that.  The vents seem to have the right temperature.  The house is being cooled down in a reasonable amount of time.  I checked for leaks in the area I was working and didn’t find any.  Any thoughts on why the humidity is increasing?

Comment: @DominickOrlando As the outside temp gets hotter you'll see a jump in humidity, at least here in Florida.  During your experiments, since the air flow is reduced in the rest of the house, the humidity will increase and it takes at least 24 hours for the AC to reduce it.  With the summer heat really getting into swing, now's the time to experiment on how the AC will work with adding those two rooms.

Comment: @jack.  I think I figured out the humidity issue.  I had some leaks in the Plenum where I was doing the work but several little leaks because it is 40 years old.  I replace that side of the Plenum today and so far the humidity issue has been much better. 

So my only concern in my test from yesterday is that the flex duct air coming out was 67° in the heat of the day versus 61 in the evening. So the R6 insulation on it was picking up a lot of heat from the attic. Any idea if 67° can call a room in 94 degree weather?  If I wrap more insulation around it do you think that would help?

Comment: @jack. The bedroom vent which is next to the closet where I was doing the test was coming out at 62.5 in the heat of the day versus 60 at night so the original ducts are keeping the air a little better insulated